# Get Type from String in C#

Tags: c#

I want to get the `Type` object from an String which contains the complete path of the class right from its namespace.

I have tried using `Type type = Type.GetType("System.Convert")` and it works but it gives me `null` when using `Type type = Type.GetType("System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex")`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I tried `Type.GetType(new Regex(@"\d").GetType().ToString());` and it still returned null, I don't think it's anything you are doing.

Comment: Type.GetType("System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089")

Comment: System.Convert works because it is in mscorlib. To find out where a type is, use `typeof(System.Convert).AssemblyQualifiedName`

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich do I just check for mscorlib, and system dlls when checking for C# classes?

Comment: If `Type.GetType` returns null without the full qualified name, then it's not in mscorlib.

Comment: @YuriyFaktorovich is there any other dll apart from system that I need to check if it is not in mscorlib?

Comment: Where are you getting these strings? Could you generate them as type value pairs of the name and the assembly qualified name?